# TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

Хочу сделать бота для расписаний общественного транспорта. Хочу получить 40 мб JSON файл(все кода станций по всему миру от Яндекса) и этот JSON закинуть в mongodb.

Вот метод возвращающий данный JSON:

```
    def get_stations_codes(self):
        ru_request = F'https://api.rasp.yandex.net/v3.0/stations_list/?apikey={self.api_key}&lang=ru_RU&format=json'
        answer = requests.get(ru_request)
        return answer.json()
```

А вот этот метод создает бд и по идее должен закинуть туда JSON преобразованный в dict:

```
def create_db(ru_codes):
    '''This method creates and insert document with station codes'''
    client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
    db = client['codes']
    codes = db.codes
    ru_codes = json.loads(ru_codes)
    codes.insert_one(ru_codes)
    print(db.insert_one(ru_codes))
```

Здесь `ru_codes` - JSON, который возвращает вышеописанный метод `get_stations_codes`.
Однако выдает ошибку:

> TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict

Даже изменив строчку `codes.insert_one(ru_codes)` на `codes.insert_one(str(ru_codes))`,все равно всплывает эта ошибка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_stations_codes` возвращает `dict`, его не нужно преобразовывать. Попробуйте убрать строку:

```
ru_codes = json.loads(ru_codes)
```

Comment: помогло, спасибо, правда сейчас вылезла ошибка pymongo.errors.DocumentTooLarge: BSON document too large (34125999 bytes) - the connected server supports BSON document sizes up to 16793598 bytes.  Но это уже совсем другая история)